# Showing my web page intead any address in web browser

Tags: php, android, wifi, html

I am trying to write a code that when user connected to wifi rotour(without internet) and then write any address in his web browser ie "google.com" or sth else, i show my webpage instead that address. This was first section and secound one is that with pushing a button on my web page I send a apk file to him and then opening that app. 
So this was all of things that i want but i know any thing just coding php and java that is my job. Please help me and show me the solution for each sectios. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for redirecting
[Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

And for the apk, just make download stream of the .apk, and the user have to install it manually after download, because you don`t have privileges to open apk-s from browser.